# Include new fortran90 module into existing huge fortran90 model

Tags: makefile, compilation, fortran, gfortran, multiple-makefiles

I am a beginner of fortran90. What I want to do is to call a new module (also fortran90) from an existing huge model which was written by fortran90. What I knew is that running fortran scripts highly depends on the compilation by gfortran using make or cmake. And `make`&`cmake` will compile the `Makefile`&`CMakefile`. I checked that, this huge model uses commands `make` with a large Makefile. The new module I wanted to use contains several `.f90` files. So it's impossible to just simply write this module into one existing .f90 file of the model...And one thing is that, I just want to use this new module in ONE subroutine in the existing fortran90 model.

For the new module, it's downloaded from GitHub and the compilation was done by `cmake`. Firstly I need to run a bash file `!sh build_steps.sh` (the `!` is used for running bash commands in python terminal). And the `!sh build_steps.sh` simply follows:

```
rm -rf build
mkdir build
cd build

FC=gfortran cmake .. -DSERIAL=1
# FC='mpif90 -qopenmp' cmake .. -DSERIAL=1

make

cd CMakeFiles/neural.dir/

mv mod_activation.mod.stamp mod_activation.o
mv mod_io.mod.stamp mod_io.o
mv mod_kinds.mod.stamp mod_kinds.o
mv mod_layer.mod.stamp mod_layer.o
mv mod_mnist.mod.stamp mod_mnist.o
mv mod_network.mod.stamp mod_network.o
mv mod_parallel.mod.stamp mod_parallel.o
mv mod_random.mod.stamp mod_random.o
mv mod_ensemble.mod.stamp mod_ensemble.o
mv mod_dense_layer.mod.stamp mod_dense_layer.o
mv mod_batchnorm_layer.mod.stamp mod_batchnorm_layer.o
mv mod_dropout_layer.mod.stamp mod_dropout_layer.o
```

Then the `CMakelists.txt` follows:

```
# cmake version, project name, language
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(neural-fortran Fortran)

# set output paths for modules, archives, and executables
set(CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/include)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

# if build type not specified, default to release
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "release")
endif()

# handle integer size
if(INT)
  message(STATUS "Configuring build for ${INT}-bit integers")
  add_definitions(-DINT${INT})
else()
  message(STATUS "Configuring build for 32-bit integers")
  add_definitions(-DINT32)
endif()

# handle real size
if(REAL)
  message(STATUS "Configuring build for ${REAL}-bit reals")
  add_definitions(-DREAL${REAL})
else()
  message(STATUS "Configuring build for 32-bit reals")
  add_definitions(-DREAL32)
endif()

if(SERIAL)
  message(STATUS "Configuring build for serial execution")
else()
  message(STATUS "Configuring build for parallel execution")
  add_definitions(-DCAF)
endif()

# compiler flags for gfortran
if(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID MATCHES GNU)

  if(SERIAL)
    message(STATUS "Configuring to build with -fcoarray=single")
    set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} -fcoarray=single")
  endif()

  if(BLAS)
    set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} -fexternal-blas ${BLAS}")
    set(LIBS "${LIBS} blas")
    message(STATUS "Configuring build to use BLAS from ${BLAS}")
  endif()

  set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} -cpp -fopenmp")
  set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG "-O0 -g -C -fbacktrace")
  set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3 -ffast-math")
endif()

# compiler flags for ifort
if(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID MATCHES Intel)

  set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} -fpp -assume byterecl,realloc_lhs -heap-arrays -qopenmp")
  set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG "-O0 -g -C -traceback")
  set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3")

  if(NOT SERIAL)
    set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} -coarray=shared")
  endif()

endif()

# compiler flags for Cray ftn
if(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID MATCHES Cray)
  set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} -h noomp")
  set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG "-O0 -g")
  set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3")
endif()

# library to archive (libneural.a)
add_library(neural src/lib/mod_activation.F90 src/lib/mod_io.F90 src/lib/mod_kinds.F90 src/lib/mod_layer.F90 src/lib/mod_dense_layer.F90 src/lib/mod_dropout_layer.F90 src/lib/mod_batchnorm_layer.F90 src/lib/mod_mnist.F90 src/lib/mod_network.F90 src/lib/mod_ensemble.F90 src/lib/mod_parallel.F90 src/lib/mod_random.F90)

# Remove leading or trailing whitespace
string(REGEX REPLACE "^ | $" "" LIBS "${LIBS}")

# tests
enable_testing()
#  mnist network_save network_sync set_activation_function
foreach(execid keras bulk ensembles training save_and_load keras_mymodel)
  add_executable(test_${execid} src/tests/test_${execid}.F90)
  target_link_libraries(test_${execid} neural ${LIBS})
  add_test(test_${execid} bin/test_${execid})
endforeach()

# foreach(execid mnist save_and_load simple sine)
#   add_executable(example_${execid} src/tests/example_${execid}.F90)
#   target_link_libraries(example_${execid} neural ${LIBS})
#   add_test(example_${execid} bin/example_${execid})
# endforeach()
```

The `Makefile` is too long, so I keep it in a google doc https://docs.google.com/document/d/10naj1WgE9P4qbILT3n85TosZCd1KISwSzGw2u5FIOwo/edit?usp=sharing. (this model is open-source...)

I knew something about bash, but nothing about `Make` and `Cmake`. So I just want to know, is there a simple way to combine this two makefiles? how can I declare the subroutine dependency in the existing makefile? or just simply import the new module in the existing fortran 90 subroutine like `import numpy` in python. Or do I need to change the dependency one by one?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Inserting a new module into your Fortran codebase is not as simple as a high-level `import numpy`, but more like building and integrating numpy with Python. You need to have specific rules in your Makefile to build the new module and link its object file with the others. Your best bet for resolving dependencies is to write a CMake build generator script for your codebase. The Makefiles will be automatically generated by the CMake. Once you have the CMake files, adding new modules to your codebase is as simple as one line addition of the new file path to the list of source files.

Comment: Hi @King, thanks for your reply! So how can I write the "CMake build generator script"? and one thing is that, since the huge Fortran90 model is compiled by Make while the new module is compiled by CMake, is there any conflict if I write "CMake build generator script"?

Comment: I could write a book in response to your question. You just have to learn CMake, which will likely take some time from you. As a potential workaround you may be able to `include "the_new_module.f90"` at the beginning of your main Fortran file, or at the beginning of some other existing module file in your code base. This way, the new module file will be automatically compiled with the rest of the code base, assuming that this new module does not have intricate dependencies on any parts of your existing codebase.

Comment: No...it's quite impossible because the module is written not by one single file but several files...

Comment: Note that there are several other tools that can automatize the build process for you, not just CMake. There is scons, waf, [FoBIS](https://github.com/szaghi/FoBiS) and I surely forgot something.

Comment: Also, I would probably keep this library separate, I would compile it separately by the existing build process and I would only use the modules using `use`, include the directory  that contains the `.mod` files using the `-I` or whatever option is used in your compiler and link the binary library in the `.so` or th e`.a` file in the linking step. That should simplify the effort greatly even though it is something else than what you ask for in your title.

Comment: Hi @VladimirF, thanks for your reply! So you mean that, just simply copy the ```.a``` and ```.mod``` file to the module and library directory of the huge model? and what do I do next? do I need to add one sentence about compilation in the original ```Makefile```? I knew that if I use command ```gfortran``` to compile, I can specify the path of ```.mod``` and ```.a``` files by ```-I```, but how could I do with the ```Makefile```?